Is it true that every argument is a complement but not every complement is an argument?
The textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 226:

Argumenthood
In the simplest cases the propositional meaning of a clause (ignoring the component contributed by the tense) can be described in terms of a semantic predicate together with one or more arguments. The semantic predicate represents some property, relation, process, action, etc., and the arguments represent the entities involved – the bearer of the property, the terms in the relation, etc. Prototypically, the semantic predicate corresponds to the syntactic predicator, and the arguments correspond to complements. In our initial example, "He always reads the paper before breakfast", the complements "he" and "the paper" are arguments of "read", but the adjuncts "always" and "before breakfast" are not: semantically, they are concerned with circumstances of the situation (frequency and temporal location respectively) rather than entities involved in the reading.

wikipedia.org:

Construed in the broad sense, many complements cannot be understood as arguments. The argument concept is tied to the predicate concept in a way that the complement concept is not.


I have some general questions:
Is it true that every argument is a complement?
If it's not true, then could you give me please those examples where arguments are not complements?
Is it true that not every complement is an argument?
If it's true, then could you give me please those examples where complements are not arguments?

And I have one specific question:
Do arguments include predicative complements or not?

P.S.:
Anticipating the popular question "Why am I thinking this or that?", I just don't know. I couldn't find enough information which I could unambiguously answer my questions with.

I've no idea whether the proposition is true or not, but I do know that the standard format for all such is every X is a Y, but not every Y is an X. In fact, even though the first every could (syntactically, semantically, just not idiomatically) be replaced by any, replacing the second instance just gives oxymoronic gibberish.

If you look at this question, you will see that different grammarians have defined 'complement' in different ways. So the answer will depend on which definition(/s) you select. Fowler, if I remember correctly, listed four different ways in which 'complement' has been defined. Doubtless someone will say that CGEL has the only worthwhile analysis ... but they do hijack existing terminology.

@EdwinAshworth In answering my questions, one could use any definition of the complement: both traditional and modern from CGEL.

Interesting question. As far as CGEL goes: I think they're intentionally being somewhat vague and hand-wavy on this topic, in order to avoid having to go too far into formal logic.

But the question obviousl hinges on what definitions are chosen. The various ways in which grammarians have used 'complement' have certainly been covered here before. See for example clauseacting as an object complement. And JL at his draconianest.

@EdwinAshworth I can't understand why you are writing this. Let's write another ten such comments under this post so not a single one of them will answer it.

I'm saying that (1) you need to agree on a working definition of 'complement' etc before it makes sense to try to answer this; (2) this problem with terminology has been covered before. You say yourself that you're encountering 'ambiguities' (which I assume are 'inconsistencies').

I think you (the OP) are confusing semantic and syntactic uses of the terms: your CGEL quote is about semantics, but the Wikipedia quote is from a section about syntax. Some people will reserve complement for semantics and argument to syntax, in which case there's a different problem in trying to equate the two. But you certainly need to specify which you mean.
